# ElasticSearch transformation, scripted_metric without nested fieldnames

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting, transformation

I created a ElasticSearch transformation like this:

```
"source": {
    "index": "input_index"
  },
  "dest" : { 
    "index" : "output_index"
  },
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": { 
      "device_id": { "terms": { "field": "device_id.keyword" }}
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "max": {
          "field": "@timestamp"
        }
      },
      "latest_doc": {
        "scripted_metric": {
           "init_script": ...,
           "map_script": ... }",
           "combine_script": "return state",
           "reduce_script": .... return last_doc   (last_doc contains document from input_index) 
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This works great, but all fields in the destination index start with "latest_doc.".
Is there a way to prevent fieldnames being preceeded with this latest_doc label ?

(Otherwise i have to use different index-templates for input indexes and output indexes)

Answer (score 1):

found a workaround, for anyone who wants to know:

added a ingest pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/remove_trailing_
{
    "processors": [{
            "script": {
                "source": """
                for(item in ctx['latest_doc'].entrySet()) {
                   def f1 = 'latest_doc.' + item.getKey();
                   def f2 = item.getKey();
                   ctx[f2] = item.getValue();
                }
                ctx.remove('latest_doc');
                """
            }
        }
    ]
}
```